# delay the execution of website page

Tags: javascript, web, loading, execution

I am developing an website and it is kinda heavy, so I need to do those loading animation that keeps the website of getting start before loading all elements and images.

Keep in mind I have a lot of CSS animation and jQuery animation so I can't use document.ready because this stops only Javascript animation not CSS animation.

Even if there's no loading animation but what is most important is to delay execution or appearance of every thing till after loading everything

[image: Loading bar]

Comment: Are you sure you can't just let the browser handle this?  Are you absolutely positive your site cannot be used at all until all of these images load?  Keep in mind that there are people on really awful connections that sometimes don't load images by choice.  Most sites don't need to do what you're asking.

Comment: some pages have animation form images that after complete it turn into clickable but when i tried to open it with slow connection it became missy

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script to your document's head tag.
Check its [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bukharim96/cgbo0nLd/21/) on JSFiddle.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    /* SimplePageLoader */
    
    // Interpreter first checks loading state
    var isLoading = true,
        overlay = document.createElement("div");
    
    // A little bit of styling
    overlay.id = "before-content-overlay";
    overlay.style.background = "#ffffff";
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    overlay.style.position = "absolute";
    overlay.style.top = "0";
    overlay.style.bottom = "0";
    overlay.style.right = "0";
    overlay.style.left = "0";
    
    // SVG Spinner
    overlay.innerHTML = "<svg class=\"lds-spinner\" width=\"64pxheight=\"64pxxmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" viewBox=\"0 0 100 100\" preserveAspectRatio=\"xMidYMid\" style=\"background: none;\"><g transform=\"rotate(0 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.9166666666666666s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(30 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.8333333333333334s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(60 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.75s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(90 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.6666666666666666s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(120 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.5833333333333334s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(150 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.5s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(180 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.4166666666666667s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(210 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.3333333333333333s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(240 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.25s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(270 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.16666666666666666s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(300 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"-0.08333333333333333s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g><g transform=\"rotate(330 50 50)\"><rect x=\"47\" y=\"24\" rx=\"9.4\" ry=\"4.8\" width=\"6\" height=\"12\" fill=\"#000000\"><animate attributeName=\"opacity\" values=\"1;0\" times=\"0;1\" dur=\"1s\" begin=\"0s\" repeatCount=\"indefinite\"></animate></rect></g></svg>";
    
    var spinner = overlay.childNodes[0];
    
    spinner.style.width = "64px";
    spinner.style.height = "64px";
    spinner.style.position = "absolute";
    spinner.style.left = spinner.style.top = "calc(50% - 32px)";
   
    // Once loaded
    window.onload = function() {
     isLoading = false;
      
     // Uncomment to test and comment/remove above statement
      // setTimeout(function() { isLoading = false }, 1000);
    };
    
    setInterval(function() {
      if (isLoading && !document.body.contains(overlay)) {
        document.body.appendChild(overlay);
      } else if (!isLoading && document.body.contains(overlay)) {
        // If loaded, overlay should disappear
        overlay.parentNode.removeChild(overlay);
      }
    }, 150);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hidden until fully loaded/mounted</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is good start thank for trying 
it detect the completion of website loading and the loading animation stops running but still the images load one by one like a miss and the css animation goes off before the loading completes